# NGINX-FPM configuration settings for magento

Tags: magento, nginx, magento-1.7, php

I am running a ecommerce website developed in magento. I have 512mb RAM and 2.6 core2duo on the server. When I send 50 requests at a time on my website it does not respond except for a few requests. I have installed varnish too. I want to know the optimal settings that i want to do for my website. I have seen that PHP-FPM is taking too much memory and cpu usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Background

We use nginx and php5-fpm on ubuntu 12 on our production machine (VCenter Virtual Machine, 4 cores, 8 GB ram). Our magento installation is heavily themed and extended. Just for kicks the other day I installed everything from scratch on a VMWare box with a default installation of Magento 1.12 EE (I needed to call them out on a bug).  I just say this so you know that we've got nginx and php5-fpm in a production environment.

What you are asking is something I think everyone struggles with using nginx and php fpm... Squeezing more performance from it. I mean, we could just use apache and php if we weren't trying to get the site performance increase right?  There are a lot answers, opinions, and case base solutions, but I'll point you to the guide I used to configure my system...

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-and-optimizing-tips-and-tricks/

Taken from the blog comments:

> ...However, the problem is indeed Magento, rather than the configuration
>   of the server. Magento is just too large and too heavy to any
>   environment. Magento hosting is really tedious and unpleasant task.

It may not answer every question you have, but there are a lot of good things to make sure you do... Like setting worker_processes = how many cores you have etc.

Personally one thing I still have trouble with is if server load gets really high (more than 5 - 10 hits per seconds) the processors are hammered. I haven't fully nailed down the problem, but adding a core and bumping the ram made a significant dent. I may increase the ram more, but at this time our user base is not seeing any site performance problems.

(Found from another site blog post:)

> Magento makes heavy use of the disk subsystem for many of its
>   operations.  Disk I/O is the biggest bottleneck, next to CPU’s
>   (cores), to optimal Magento performance.
>
> This is why Magento performs so poorly in cloud environments where the
>   storage is on a SAN shared with countless other users and under stress
>   at random times causing inconsistent performance.
>
> SSD’s (Solid State Drives) configured in a RAID1+0 disk array locally
>   outperforms 15.5K SAS drives in the same RAID configuration.
>
> A local Database is also the key to peak performance with Magento
>
> A remote database introduces latency due system calls and network
>   saturation.  If you must use a remote database you should make sure
>   you are on a private VLAN and not sharing an over saturated network
>   connection, which is common for even the largest hosting providers. 
>   In the best of network environments, remote database will NOT be as
>   fast as local database for a variety of reasons.
>
> CPU speed and the number of CPU’s is also incredibly important to
>   optimal Magento performance.  You can get an idea of the power of the
>   high end CPU that you are using at the following URL - if the CPU is
>   not listed here it is not considered ‘high end‘ by the benchmark
>   “PassMark Software“;
>
> http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html
>
> Performance based web servers, such as LiteSpeed, make use of multiple
>   CPU’s (cores) as does the MySQL server, with a proper configuration. 
>   Using a performance based web server can significantly improve your
>   applications performance against the Apache web server software.
>
> Trying to rewrite or convert/compile Magento is not a solution - it’s
>   a bandaid at best.  You will be locked out of any future upgrades
>   (without a significant amount of development time to rewrite and test
>   your changes) and with each upgrade we continue to see speed
>   improvements.  Core changes to Magento should NEVER be performed, core
>   changes to Magento should NEVER be performed - this defeats the OOP
>   model that Magento employs.
>
> In the end, as we have said before, Magento can not achieve optimal
>   performance without a significant investment in the infrastructure on
>   which the application runs.  If you are considering running Magento
>   and are wanting to do so on a budget hosting provider understand that
>   you simply can not and will not achieve peak performance with this
>   application.
>
> **Magento requires resources due to it’s complex nature - you can not
>   provide the necessary resources on a budget hosting provider as the
>   costs for this type of hardware system is not inexpensive.**

Comment: As a follow up, I installed Varnish in front of nginx as a caching method and the results were pretty good. Not perfect, but it helped alot and wasn't too hard to do.  If you are interested, let me know.

Comment: Why didn't you use nginx caching? Just interested

Answer (score 0):

You should increase memory more than 512m, because nginx + php-fpm and varnish run use more than memory of system. i conduct overflow and php process can not enough ram to excute